# What is the geometric relation between rows and columns of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Consider the set of columns of a $n\times m$ real matrix $A$. Clearly, the (ordered) set of columns of a matrix is in bijection with the corresponding (ordered) set of rows.
Can any general statement be made about the geometric relations between such sets of rows and columns?

For example, if I consider a $2\times2$ matrix, I can picture its rows and columns as points in the plane. How are these two pairs of points related? Representing this for matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}2& \cos(\theta)\\0& \sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$ varying $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ I for example get the following:

[image]

where black arrows correspond to the columns of the matrix, and the red arrows to the associated rows.

Is there a good way to describe the general relations between such sets?

To add some further context: what spurred the question are general results such as the fact that the rank of the set of rows equals that of the set of columns, or the fact that for square matrices the columns are orthonormal iff the rows are. It's clear that there's tight relations between the collections of rows and columns, and that their geometries are linked. I'm essentially trying to understand if anything more general can be said to this effect.

Comment: Consider a $2\times 3$ matrix. Do you still have a bijection?

Comment: As pointed out by @PierreCarre, if the matrix is not square you can't have a bijection. Also $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1}$ gives a counter-example in the square case. I  think the best you can say is that the rows and columns span subspaces of the same rank.

Comment: @PierreCarre I'd argue you still do, yes. It's a bijection between a pair of 3-dimensional vectors, and a triple of 2-dimensional vectors

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not sure what you mean. In your example the rows are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$, and the columns are $(1,-1)$ and $(1,-1)$. What's the contradiction?

Comment: There are two rows and just one column, so the rows and columns aren't in bijection.

Comment: @robarthan I don't understand what you mean. Let me reiterate that I'm referring to the *ordered* sets of rows/columns, in case that's what's bringing the confusion. So there's two rows and two columns there. I mean it's rather tautological that there's a bijection in general. You cannot change a row without affecting the columns

Comment: Bijections aren't very interesting for ordered sets (viewed as sets of index-element pairs): they just tell you about the index sets and not the elements.

Comment: @gls A bijection means that you can establish a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of two sets... If the sets have a different number of elements (assuming they are finite), you most certainly cannot have a bijection.

Comment: Bijection matters aside, even for square matrices there are issues. If we identify columns as Cartesian plane vectors (one of two common conventions), then rows are naturally elements of the _dual_ vector space. Drawing rows as vectors in the _same_ plane perpetrates an isomorphism not naturally defined by vector space structure of the plane. <> Separately, there are twelve ways to pick an ordered pair of components from a set of four matrix entries. Putting the four entries into a $2 \times 2$ matrix and considering rows versus columns looks unnatural from this perspective as well.

Comment: Even ordered sets cannot contain repeating elements. It is list. Mapping from rows to columns has not much sense in general case. The only specific property of such mapping that there is at least one component which is stable (if you map 1st row to 1st column and so on). In case of 2×2 matrix this gives situation shown in question animation.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang regarding the "non-naturality" of the duality: doesn't talking about matrices like I'm doing here amount to a choice of inner product, which then fixes a notion of duality? This aside, what spurred the question is that we know that there are relations in some cases of interest. For square matrices, columns form an orthonormal system iff rows do. For non-square ones, columns being orthonormal implies all subsets of rows (of suitable size) are as well. There are notable cases in which interesting properties of one set reflect in those of the other

Comment: granted, those are not necessarily direct relations between one set and the other, but rather properties of one set reflecting in similar properties of the other. But the two sets are then also tightly related by the constraint of them having to fit into a single matrix. I agree that there are issues with thinking of them as ordered sets or not, but I don't seem them as particularly insurmountable (maybe we could redefine the problem thinking of the columns and rows as defined up to permutations of their elements; many geometric properties would still make sense on such objects)

Comment: One well known theorem: the dimension of the span of the rows equals the dimension of the span of the columns.

Comment: @glS Your comment about orthonormality is helpful as motivation. As you say, for square matrices the duality isomorphism may be viewed as a choice of inner product, and the dual basis to an orthonormal basis is also orthonormal in the induced inner product. <> "Orthonormal columns" is a restrictive situation and I still don't see any extension to arbitrary square matrices, but I now have a better idea where the question originates.